# v-select component is not showing selected option in v-select box

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, dropdownbox, v-select

I am facing one problem while working with v-select component. V-select component is not showing selected item... It is showing options in dropdown but after selecting it is showing blank in select box.

 This is the problem-
[image]

 Dropdown is showing.. but not showing anything after selecting. 
[image]
Like this.. It is blank.
Here is my code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select
      label="broadcast"
      v-model="broadcast_"
      :options="broadcasters"
      :reduce="(broadcast) => broadcast.id"
    >
      <template v-slot:option="option">{{ option.name }}</template>
    </v-select>
  </div>
</template>
        
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import vSelect from "vue-select";
Vue.component("v-select", vSelect);
    
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      broadcasters: [
        {
          name: "ABC Live",
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Disney",
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          name: "24x7 Broadcast",
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
      broadcast_: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    broadcast_(val) {
      console.log(val);  //It prints desire data (i.e broadcast id)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you wanted with your `:reduce` statement.
But if you change your code where

```
label="broadcast"
```

to

```
label="name"
```

or

```
label="id"
```

You will get the text in the selectbox

Comment: :reduce is used to store id in value and not the object... btw thanks it is working.